How does a digital multimeter measure?
I have a pulsating signal (always positive) with a frequency of 50 Hz and a true RMS multimeter.

Should I measure the voltage with the multimeter on DC or AC? What´s the multimeter doing in each case?
If a lead-acid battery is being charged with these pulses and I´m trying to measure the charge current, which also is a pulsating signal of 50 Hz, should I measure in AC or DC?
If the current is measured with a shunt, then through an amplifier and finally to a pic ADC, what type of filter should I make for the signal to be like the one in the multimeter?


You can measure both ACrms & DCavg and also perhaps Vmax DC (depending on DMM)  Why not try it and report results above with a question?  Various methods prefer to use a DSO as  DMMs tend to be low BW. (<20kHz) but if your currents are step voltages, you want to determine Vavg DC and also Vrms AC for experimenting with Pchg or Irms AC charge rates. for 1C or less but you may also want 10C pk for good batteries 1us to restore some life but not add heat. I suspect you want to measure battery ESR vs SOC so you know how to measure this right?

Yes, I know that with an DSO will be a lot more accurate, but in that case, I can see what I'm measuring, the multimeter gives only a number, and that's my doubt... What do you mean with step voltages?

the voltage change after a step current at 50 Hz with DSO to define time durations for ADC d.f. etc using a DAC programmable Howland Current sink/source with emitter follower or equiv.

Regarding the 3rd question, a moving average filter in software is pretty much equivalent to what the multimeter is doing. Same as a hardware RC lowpass filter.

@Lundin I think about an RC lowpass filter, but what cut-off frequency should I use? My IC ADC, Zinmax=1Kohm. So I should be careful with the values chosen. Any recommendations for testing it?

Larger cap means that the resulting sine wave will have a smaller amplitude/less oscillation, so that's the way to go if you are interested in the average only.

@Lundin What about the cut-off frequency?

@samuelmattio The lower the better, supposedly.

It depends on what you're actually trying to measure. If you want to know the average charge current, you might want to add a low-value shunt resistor (or a Hall sensor that works with DC) and measure the DC voltage on your DMM, bypassing the AC true RMS function. It's also likely the DC current function will do this directly.
Often the meters will AC-couple and then measure the RMS value of the resulting signal, which does not have a lot of meaning in your case.
Same thing would apply for average current measurement with a data acquisition system, you'd just need a current measurement circuit and a low-pass filter and adequate sample rate to get a good average without undue aliasing.

For measuring current, I always used an amperometric clamp in DC mode, this is my "reference measure". Now that I'm trying to make a meter myself, I realize that I don't know what I'm measuring... What value is the clamp reading? Because when I measure with a shunt, and an amplifier, and then making an average, It seems that the values coincide more with measuring with clamp in AC mode.

Do you have an oscilloscope?

Yes, I have an analog one

How can a linear circuit with a pulse become non-linear when measured?
When it is clipped by the amplifier.
I suspect you want to measure battery ESR vs SOC using pulse charging perhaps with the flyback method or rectified currents with high dV/dt limited by ESR.
Do you know how to measure this?
Then measure all aspects of the pulse. Peak/rms {V,I} ,Pavg, duty cycle and correlate with DSO to choose best test method to create with ADC.

My suggestions

(1) Measure Vdc and store results for a few sec with 1A CC load and a look-up table for % SOC
(2) Pulse load ΔmV/1A = ESR [mΩ] for last 2 values.
(3) Measure all with DMM and DSO and examine critical inputs and outputs, d.f. peak, rms , C rate, life aging effects on ESR, Wh capacity for each charge for research using only 60% SOC each cycle or whatever.
(4) Make a list of goals. Compare charge methods for efficient, effective lifespan Wh delivery from SOC before after or total Coulombs to charge X % SOC.
Why not try your DMM in both AC rms and DC and compare with a DSO the report results above with a question?  Various methods prefer to use a DSO as  DMMs tend to be low BW. (<20kHz) but if your currents are step voltages, you want to determine Vavg DC and also Vrms AC for experimenting with Pchg or Irms AC charge rates. for 1C or less but you may also want 10C pk for good batteries 1us to restore some life but not add heat.
Consider this IC for current sense.
https://static.3peak.com/res/doc/ds/Datasheet_TPA191.pdf
If you wish to measure bipolar currents then Vr = Vref/2 for an offset input.
RMS applies to V or I as the average of N rms cycles for some time interval. So fin and fADC need to be known to prevent flicker.

As I said in another answer,  I realize that I don't know what I'm measuring, I always used a clamp in DC mode for measuring how much current my circuit is delivering to the battery, what type of measure I'm reading? I have already designed a PCB with this IC, that doesn't need a shunt, tell me what you think about it . https://ar.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1115/ACS711_Datasheet-3178445.pdf

Currently the IC that I'm using, it has an 32Mhz clock. In the ADC, Fosc/4 is being used, so 8Mhz in ADC, and always a 50hz input frequency. How should I prevent aliasing?

Looks OK except 100mV/A if Ok for your resolution 2:13 Am Laterz

My current technique for measuring 50hz current with shunt and amplifier and using a zero cross detector is: When zero cross is detected, read signal every 0.1mS, stacking it in a variable "acc", and when another zero cross detection occurs: acc/200

With low AC content and if small step-shape AC voltage over DC your Vavg is not too far from Vrms. - sq.root(sum of squares)

I´m currently trying this and the "output" value of making RMS of input signal is linear with AC mode measuring with amp. clamp.  When I measure with DC mode, it isn´t linear. Do you have any ideas why this happen?

is the input nonlinear?

It's not I think... I'm measuring how much current, with a INA189 and a 1.5 mOhm resistor. The current comes from 2 SCR controlled by MCU (the SCR's are rectifying a center tap transformer, and then charging the battery )

Vp + Vdc is not = Vrms unless Vpp is very small

What calculation should I do? Considering that I want the same value as amperometric clamp in DC mode.

Show with a DSO your ADC signal is not clipped and estimate the "crest factor" = Peak / Average with rise time.  Check for common mode noise interference.  Attach your test results in a spreadsheet.
